# difficult in understanding some logic circuits

Tags: expression, logical-operators

Finding it difficult to get the logic expression for this circuit? Help will be appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KuQb.png)

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: hi much appreciated for the reply , i cant seem to get the logic expression in order to start on my truth table

Comment: Do you recognise all elements?

Comment: yes as to it starts with an AND gate where b and c then follows to a NOT gate where A is , is that what your referring to ?

Comment: Yes. And are you familiar with boolean algebra and DeMorgan laws?

Comment: briefly i have gone through the laws aswell as the assocative and commutative law, im new to programming so im trying to get a great understanding of my course as my knowledge is minimal

Comment: This is mathematical logic fundamentals, not exactly programming, but certainly part of the foundations. I am posting a detailed solution, please let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed solution, I hope (i) that the steps are clear, and (ii) that my calculation is correct :-)

The circuit has four logical gates: an `AND` gate with output `X = B*C` (short for `B AND C`), a `NOT` gate which inverts the value of `A` yielding `A'` (short for `NOT A`), a `NOR` gate with inputs `A'` and `X` and output `Y = (A' + X)'` (short for `NOT ((NOT A) OR X))`) and a final `AND` gate with inputs `Y`, `A` and `B` and output `Z = A*B*Y` (short for `Z = A AND B AND Y`). The expression for `Z` is then:

```
Z = A * B * Y = A * B * ( (A' + X)' ) = A * B * { [A' + (B*C)]' }
```

Repeatedly applying DeMorgan laws to the expression in the brackets yields:

```
[A' + (B*C)]' = A'' * (B*C)' = A *(B' + C')
```

So

```
Z = A * B * [ A *(B' + C') ] = A * B * A * (B' + C')
```

Since `A*B*A = A*A*B = (A*A)*B` and `A*A = A` this yields

```
Z = A * B * (B' + C') = A * B * B' + A * B * C'
```

And finally, since `B * B' = 0`, `X * 0 = 0`:

```
Z = 0 + A * B * C' = A * B * C' = A AND B AND (NOT C)
```